# Java - Including array declaration inside function call?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to declare an int array in the call of a method, is this possible in Java?

I am relatively new to Java but have some python knowledge. I was trying to find an equivalent of (in python3):

```
foo([1,2,3,4])  #python
```

Declaring the array first works ofc:

```
int[] data = {1,2,3,4,5};
printArray(reverseArray(data));
```

But I was wondering if something such as:

```
printArray(reverseArray(int[] {1,2,3,4,5}));
```

Was possible.

I am working under Netbeans and my above attempted solution is reported as
a 'not a statement' error. 
Also, would:

```
int[] data = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}
```

be more correct than simply:

```
int[] data = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to add the `new` keyword so that it creates a new object:

```
printArray(reverseArray(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}));
```

If you define your `reverseArray` method to take `int...` instead of `int[]`, then you can also use the following, which I'd argue is more readable:

```
printArray(reverseArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Comment: Is there also any efficiency difference in using int... and letting the compiler handle the array creation or is that purely syntactic sugar?

Comment: I’m pretty sure it’s just sugar, but even if it provided *some* efficiency benefit, I’d prefer it regardless because of the readability improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `new` keyword as below,

```
printArray(reverseArray(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}));
```